# Angular Microfrontend with Module Federation intercept HTTP request in host application

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I need to intercept all HTTP request coming from all the remotes in my host application in order to restart a timer that monitor the user inactivity. All applications are using Angular with Webpack Module Federation.
Any ideas?

The best should be the host app interceptor could intercept all requests, alternatives solutions i found are:

- sharing a global variable through the object *window* resetting it from the remote whenever a request is made from it and increment in host app every second
- using custom events to communicate to the host app that a request has been made and the host has to reset the count

Which is the preferrable solution?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this situation this week, and for me the best fit was creating an angular  library that exposes the interceptor, and share this library between the shell and the microfrontends through module federation.

Comment: Can you please share the code or repo? We are trying to achieve the same . Should we really want to add the interceptor in host app ? can we not only add it in remote app ?